# React Native FlatList inside of ScrollView

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scrollview, react-native-reanimated, flatlist

In my page I must have these 2 features:

First i must detect when list reach the end.

Second i must do some animation on scrolling of List

Here is my current code :

```
<Animated.ScrollView {...props} onScroll={onScroll({y}, {height}, {height: layoutH})}>
  <FlatList
    {...props}
    onEndReached={({distanceFromEnd}) => {
      if (distanceFromEnd < 0) {
        return;
      }
      if (hasNextPage && !isFetchingNextPage) {
        fetchNextPage();
      }
    }}
  />
</Animated.ScrollView>
```

But as you know it has some performance issues and `onEndReached` is only called when the component is mounted, Not on reaching the end of the List.

If I fix height for my FlatList and put it in a `<View>` with the style of `flex:1, height: Dimensions.get('window').height` my `onScroll` method will not call and work anymore.

How can I fix my code to remove the performance issue?

If you want to see my onScroll function here is it:

```
export const onScroll = (
  contentOffset: {
    x?: Animated.Node<number>;
    y?: Animated.Node<number>;
  },
  contentSize: {
    width?: Animated.Node<number>;
    height?: Animated.Node<number>;
  },
  layoutMeasurement: {
    width?: Animated.Node<number>;
    height: Animated.Node<number>;
  },
) =>
  Animated.event([
    {
      nativeEvent: {
        contentOffset,
        contentSize,
        layoutMeasurement,
      },
    },
  ]);
```

react-native: 0.63.4

react-native-reanimated: 2.0.0